# torque trqauthd keep failing

Tags: hpc, pbs, torque

When I run qstat, I get following error:

```
socket_connect_unix failed: 15137

socket_connect_unix failed: 15137

socket_connect_unix failed: 15137

qstat: cannot connect to server (null) (errno=15137) could not connect to trqauthd

qstat: Error (15137 - could not connect to trqauthd)
```

I run "`ps aux | grep trqauthd`"
and found the `trqauthd` is listed in the process.

If I rerun the `trqauthd`, everything will work and the `ps` will list two `trqauthd`.

it will work for 5-6 days and then fail again.

Answer (score 0):

If the daemon process is still there, but will not respond, and restarting it is the only way to correct the problem, then this just sounds like a bug. You might check with the developers via the torqueusers mailing list to see if perhaps they can guide you on doing something like running it in gdb and generating a core for debugging. The newest versions have added systemd support to replace the old init-style scripts, so you could add a check-and-restart service directive, or you could create a cron script that restarts (or kills and restarts...) trqauthd every so often, just to prevent work interruptions.